# I make a 2 layer CNN and I need to draw a diagram of it. How to draw a diagram for my CNN?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, diagram

It is my network structure. I used visualkeras but it was not practical and I tried to use NN-SVG but I couldn't.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (10,8), padding='same',  
    activation='relu',activity_regularizer=l2(0.0001),input_shape= 
    (n_timesteps, 16,1))
    model.add(Conv2D(10,( 10,4), activation='relu', 
    padding='same'))#,activity_regularizer=l2(0.001
    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: [Have you tried `plot_util()`?](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model)

Comment: NO, but I'll try it.thanks